# WP Query taxonomy posts

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I am building a wordpress theme from scratch. I have this taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_cat_slider' );

function create_cat_slider() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'sliderType','post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Slider' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

I have two posts attached to this taxonomy [image]

[image]

Now I have this following loop. It should create two buttons for the slider (the number of posts related to the taxonomy should be equal to the number of buttons created). As stated above, I have to posts related to the taxonomy. The issue is that after the WHILE is executed I will end up with 7 buttons. Been trying to fing a solution for this for the past several hours. Even with the codex in front, being my first theme, I find this quite hard.

```
                    $args = array(
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'sliderType'
                        )
                    );
                    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if($custom_query->have_posts()) :
                        //echo $custom_query->found_posts;
                        $i = 0;
                        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
                            if($i == 0)
                                $active = 'class="active"';
                            else
                                $active = '';

                            echo '<a href="#" data-target="#bigSlider" data-slide-to="' . $i . '" ' . $active . '></a>';
                            $i++;    
                        endwhile;
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
```

LE: The current version of the code:
Taxonomy

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_cat_slider' );

    function create_cat_slider() {
        register_taxonomy(
            'slider_ype','post',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Slider' ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'slidertype' )
            )
        );
    }
```

Query

```
                $args = array(
                    'tax_query' => array
                    (
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'slidertype',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'slidertype'
                        )
                    )
                );
                $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: if the code above is the issue, the only explanation is that there are 7 posts returned by your query. if you pop this `echo $custom_query->post_count;` just after running the query it will tell you. Other reasons may be a second loop running, etc. But that is not caused by the above

Comment: Well, the issue is that I have 2 posts related to that taxonomy and 7 posts in total. I want only those 2 posts displayed. That's what I am trying to achieve, tho' so far without success.

Comment: Hmm something not right, start with the obvious ones, change the tax name to lowercase `slidertype` and define the `slug` as the same in the register function. Also define the post status in wp query to pubish.

Comment: I changed the name to lowercase, tho' I do not know what do you mean by defining the slug. Do you mean rewriting the slug ?

Comment: yes https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy just in case :) although the lowercase should have worked...but just thinking of something here, im not sure wp stores which taxonomy a post belongs to rather than a specific term, maybe try a tax query with all the terms specified?

Comment: Yes, but I have a taxonomy more like a category. So the terms that I should use in the query are (as shown in the pictures above) 'Big Slider Home' (or with the slug 'big-slider-home' ?

Comment: Also, I read the codex related to tax_query and apparently I haven't done this 'wp_set_object_terms( 123, 'Bob', 'person' );' . I mean, I haven't attached the taxonomy to any posts but I thought it is done automatically once you check the taxonomy to a post. I also edited the main post with the current version of the code

Comment: id say @Pieter Goosen has given you the answer below, you need to reference the ea term of the taxonomy to check against the posts.  'wp_set_object_terms( 123, 'Bob', 'person' );' is the programatic way of setting terms, if you select the tick box, wp has a method to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to query all the posts attached to a specific taxonomy.

The only way to do this is to get all the terms attached to the taxonomy and then pass all the term ID's to a `tax_query` in your custom query

You can try the following: (*Requires PHP 5.4+ and this is only the important parts. Also note, you have mispelled `sliderType` ;-)*)

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 'sliderType', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'sliderType',
            'terms' => $term_ids
        ]
    ]
];
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you, however, just need to query posts from a specific term in a taxonomy, you can simply just pass the term ID or slug with the relevant field value to the query

```
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'sliderType',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'relevant-term-slug'
        ]
    ]
];
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: That's it, got it working and I also understood how to deal with taxonomies. Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy ;-)